# What's the difference between a souffle and a mousse?

Tags: language, mousse, souffle

I thought souffles would be baked, while mousses would be only whipped, but I've seen recipes for cooked mousses before. Is this just a case of using the wrong name for the wrong recipe or are there important differences between them?

Comment: Can you link one of those cooked mousses?

Comment: http://www.epicurious.com/recipes/food/views/Cauliflower-Mousse-235759
or
http://www.ifood.tv/recipe/fish-mousse-with-bercy-sauce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no strict delineation between these two terms.  Either can be savory or sweet.

Some common differences are:

- Mousses may get their foaminess from  from plain whipped egg whites, a meringue, whole eggs, whipped cream, or  something else; a souffle is always leavened by whipped egg whites.
- Mousses (except for some seafood mousses, which are gently poached) are rarely cooked as a whole dish; souffles are always baked to get additional rise.
- Mousses are almost always served cold; souffles are usually served hot, immediately out of the oven to retain the additional rise they get in the heat of the oven.

One might consider souffles a type of baked mousse, much as quiches are a specific type of tart, but that terminology is rarely used.

See also:

[Ochef](http://www.ochef.com/answers/1647.htm)

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion

- A soufflé is something that requires heat and will "rise" when cooked
- A mousse does not "rise" and is general served uncooked

Answer (score -1):

You can demould the mousse but the soufflé doesn't demould.

Comment: If somebody is considering flagging this as "very low quality": it seems to be an honest attempt to answer the question, and as such, there is no reason to delete it. If you think that the answer is factually incorrect, or not helpful for another reason (e.g. lacking explanation), the correct action is to downvote it. Here a reminder when the Very low quality flag is supposed to be used: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93606/149055.